# How to get deeper in the JSON body of a chainlink req.add("path") request? Add 2+ paths

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I can get the results of the `chainlink` path with `req.add("path", "chainlink")`

However, I want to return the price value, of `"chainlink", "USD"`. The output json has two paths, how do I reach the second path to get the price value?

```
  function requestLINKPrice() 
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(JOB, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=chainlink&vs_currencies=usd");
    req.add("path", "chainlinkUSD");
    req.addInt("times", 100);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(ORACLE, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }
```

Here is the JSON response of the API

```
{
  chainlink: {
    usd: 3.78
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [copy adapter](https://docs.chain.link/docs/adapters#copy) with the `copyPath` syntax.

```
string[] memory copyPath = new string[](2);
copyPath[0] = "chainlink";
copyPath[1] = "USD";
req.addStringArray("copyPath", copyPath);
```

Here is the whole function.

```
  function requestLINKPrice() 
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(JOB, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=chainlink&vs_currencies=usd");
    string[] memory copyPath = new string[](2);
    copyPath[0] = "chainlink";
    copyPath[1] = "USD";
    req.addStringArray("copyPath", copyPath);
    req.addInt("times", 100);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(ORACLE, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }
```